# How do I copy the files from the latest directory created within a directory?

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

Let's say that I have directories like these:
`~/Desktop/a`
`~/Desktop/b/some_files`

Directory b was created after but it's not certain, is there a way to understand and place into a variable which of the folder in Desktop is newer?

Hope that clear enough..

Comment: Many file systems do not store a creation date.  Which file system do you use?

Comment: Another problem: ext4 saves creation date but `stat` from `coreutils` cannot display it. [Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50177/birth-is-empty-on-ext4)

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is "no".

As @Cyrus said, not all filesystems store creation time (or transmit them, in case of NFSv3), and even if they all did, as his link mentions, the coreutils people are waiting for xstat(2).

But if you have a more specific case, e.g. the directories don't get modified after their creation, or if your definition of "newer" is based on last modification time rather than creation time, then @dibery's answer would work.

Answer (score -1):

```
newfolder=`ls -c ~/Desktop/a ~/Desktop/b/ | head -n 1`
```

You can then retrieve the value by `echo $newfolder`.

Comment: Yes, it's reasonable to think that `-c` means create, but if you check you `man ls` you'll find `-c, --ctime     Sort by change time; list ctime with --long.
-C, --multi-column
                List entries by columns.` . Best to delete this answer, as comments above stating some OS's don't store the creation date is very correct for the *nix world of systems. Good luck.